# Phrase like "sth is love sth is life"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I was just wondering if anything like the english expression "sth is love, sth is life" exists in japanese.

Preferably as close as it gets to the english wording.

---

**Edit**
It seems like my question wasn't clear enough so i'm going to try and clarify with an example:

Some people say for example "Stackoverflow is love, stackoverflow is life" to express how much they like stackoverflow.

Comment: what do you mean by sth?

Comment: "Something is, love something is live" = "A is, love A is live"?

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I don't understand this expression. Can you give some context on how this is used?

Comment: Sorry, as you may have guessed english is not my first language... I mistakenly wrote live instead of life. I added a really simple example, but maybe this expression is less common than I thought...

Answer (score 2):

This likely will not fit into Japanese culture very well, but a direct (literal) translation would be something to the effect of:

> ___は愛｛あい｝であり、命｛いのち｝である。

---

Lets break it down.

**__**: is the noun in question.

**は**: subject marker

**愛｛あい｝**: Love

**であり**:  This is a conjugation of である, a somewhat archaic form of the 'to be' verb.  The Base II conjugation is for paring with ます、but this conjugation without ます can also mean that your thought isn't finished, and that there is more to follow.

**命｛いのち｝**: Life

**である**: Plain form to be verb.  This is somewhat archaic in nature, so it gives this phrase a proverb type feel to it.  Honestly, in my opinion である sounds much cooler than です。Anyway, I say this is somewhat archaic because である is still widely used today in various circumstances.  Using it to end a sentence, however, is not common.  If you were to use it to end a sentence, you would be speaking in an older style, hence the reason it's somewhat archaic.

Comment: I like this, but to give the same emphasis on phrasing, maybe 命こそである. Completely an opinion though, because as you said, it's definitely not a native expression

Comment: I don't know of any ことわざ that would work for this either.  As for the use of こそ、I could see it going either way, we'll have to see what the 日本人 think.

Comment: definitely. I think I'm going on the emphasis of the English phrase that life = everything, thus life > love, so it's being escalated via emphasis of repetition

Comment: Oh, good point.  I still can't decide between the two, so I'm leaving it as it is to keep it simple. @psosuna

Comment: in a way it seems like using こそ is somewhat pliable here, for example: Xは愛であり、命こそである, or Xは愛であり、Xこそも命である

Comment: Right. である is the version of です・ます style, and is good for an academic or political statement while です・ます style is the standard to talk to people.

Comment: @karlalou, can you explain that a little further?

Comment: @ajsmart mm.. what should I say.. where you say これが結論です in plain style, です・ます調, you say これが結論である in だ・である調. You are recommended to choose だ・である調 when you write a thesis for a college degree, but I find news from government or NHK usually use です・ます調 to talk to us. But NHK uses だ・である調 for their documentaries, if my memory is correct.

Comment: `Xは愛であり、命こそである` `Xは愛であり、Xこそも命である` --> 「命こそである」はおかしいです。 To use こそ, it should be like 「 **Xこそ**命である」「 **Xこそが**命である」「Xこそ愛であり、Xこそ命である」「Xこそが愛であり、Xこそが命である」

Answer (score 2):

> Phrase like “sth is love sth is life”
>   "Stackoverflow is love, stackoverflow is life"

As in English, in Japanese also the subject comes first, but the verb comes at the end of the sentence.

We don't have any space in between words, but each word is connected by a particle.

When talking about a general idea, the particle **は** indicates the theme (subject) of the sentence, at the same time connects it to the next word.

So, for example,

> スタック・オーバーフロー**は**愛{あい}、スタック・オーバーフロー**は**命{いのち}